# Heroku pushing old version of app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I am fairly new to Rails. I am building a simple news app. Yesterday, I deleted my app in heroku and created a new app with the exact same name. Now, whenever I push to heroku using git, it doesn't update new database items. I added a new table column named "slug" to a model I have called "Posts," and it doesn't appear in heroku. It does appear in my local version. I think the new app is hooked up to the old repository.

1. How do I check what repository is being sent to heroku?
2. How do I check what repository my current app is hooked up to?
3. How do I connect the new repository with the new app?

I'm sure this is fairly basic. I'm completely stuck. Here are the logs from Heroku:

```
2016-10-25T18:08:19.030783+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-10-25T18:08:19.030726 #3] FATAL -- : [27319deb-f2fb-403a-8ed9-4d8d21688c59] NoMethodError (undefined method `slug' for #<Post:0x007f25b7751b18>):
2016-10-25T18:08:19.030494+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-10-25T18:08:19.030426 #3] FATAL -- : [27319deb-f2fb-403a-8ed9-4d8d21688c59]   
2016-10-25T18:08:19.031009+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-10-25T18:08:19.030949 #3] FATAL -- : [27319deb-f2fb-403a-8ed9-4d8d21688c59] app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:30:in `create'
2016-10-25T18:08:19.030857+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-10-25T18:08:19.030807 #3] FATAL -- : [27319deb-f2fb-403a-8ed9-4d8d21688c59]   
2016-10-25T18:08:19.030930+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-10-25T18:08:19.030878 #3] FATAL -- : [27319deb-f2fb-403a-8ed9-4d8d21688c59] app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:31:in `block in create'
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your new code has made it to Heroku or you wouldn't be getting the slug error. You probably forgot to run the migrations on Heroku to create the new slug column.

To run the migrations on Heroku, run the following from the terminal:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: So the HTML edits seem to make it through, but the database is not migrating. I've tried running heroku run rake:db migrate several times and it just won't budge. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you write a migration to create the new column?